# Linux Find command without display error messages

Tags: bash, find

I have to create the compose the following **find** command but I can't do it.

> Search the entire file system all files that end with ".h" or ".so" without display
>   error messages due to lack of access rights to the file (permission denided). 
>   It is not allowed use sudo to run the find command, (obviously root access) and even redirect standard error to / dev / null Blockquote

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `find -name "*.h" -o -name "*.so" 2>/dev/null`

Comment: It's not allowed to redirect to /dev/null.
This is what I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using gnu find you can do:

```
find / -type d ! -readable -prune -o \( -name '*.so' -o -name '*.h' \) -print
```

`-type d ! -readable -prune` will skip directories that are not readable by the user running this `find` command.